# IM app, how to ensure the other side received my message?

Tags: ios, networking, instant-messaging

I am writing a IM app on iOS, and not sure about how to ensure that the other side has received my message. Could anyone give me some suggestions or existing frameworks?

Comment: Are you using a server to facilitate the communication or are you sending messages directly from one device to another?

Comment: @drewag, I am using Pubnub and sending messages directly from one client to another. However, if necessary, I can store messages through my own server.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the device that receives a message send data back that confirms the message has been received. Most likely each message would be assigned a unique id that the receiving device would send back so that it knows specifically which message was received.

I am not familiar with Pubnub but looking quickly at their SDK it looks like you can send messages both directions on a single channel, or else you could setup one channel for sending messages and one channel for confirming messages.